# Zend table creation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

```
$elementDecoration = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Description',
        'Errors',
        array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'valign' => 'TOP')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
        array('Errors'),
        array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr'))
            );


        $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
        $username->setLabel('username')
        ->setDecorators($elementDecoration)
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('NotEmpty');
```

Output like below

```
<tr>
    <td id="username-label">
        <label for="username" class="required">username</label>
    </td>
<td valign="TOP">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
        <ul class="errors"><li>Value is required and can't be empty</li></ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But i want output like below

```
  <tr>
    <td>User Name:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><input name="username"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="error_msg" colspan=2>Required</td>
  </tr>
```

1. as well i want same like above.
2. as well, want to remove ul li.

Answer (score 0):

please read and understand the following:

To render the form into a table:

```
$form->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'table')),
    'Form'
));
```

Plus, you'll need to ensure the elements and labels are in table data
and table rows:

```
$form->setElementDecorators(array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('decorator' => array('td' => 'HtmlTag'), 'options' => array('tag' => 'td')),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'td')),
    array('decorator' => array('tr' => 'HtmlTag'), 'options' => array('tag' => 'tr')),
));
```

For your 'submit' button, you'll want to modify the decorators so the
submit spans both columns:

```
 $form->submit->setDecorators(array(
        array(
            'decorator' => 'ViewHelper',
            'options' => array('helper' => 'formSubmit')),
        array(
            'decorator' => array('td' => 'HtmlTag'),
            'options' => array('tag' => 'td', 'colspan' => 2)),
        array(
            'decorator' => array('tr' => 'HtmlTag'),
            'options' => array('tag' => 'tr')),
    ));
```

The above code will give you table like below. Now you can edit upto your need.
Your last table structure was not clear as the first  has only 1 column and the 2nd  has a  with colspan=2.

```
<form>
 <table>
   <tr>
   <td>Label</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="test"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan=2><input type="submit"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: i am looking like table tr td label name  tr td input box tr td label name tr td input box

Comment: I was not clear with your requirement from the description you gave so i gave you an idea how to use Zend helper, now you can edit it accordingly.

Comment: please look at the code. 1st tr contains 1 td so how could 2nd and 3rd tr contain colspan=2 in td

Comment: there is class to created the textbox,  but i dont see there is a sperate class for label, we can just append the string the element class function itself using setLabel